# Android Jitsi SDK: throws exception "Failed to load config"

Tags: android, jitsi-meet

On Android API32, I am using Jitsi SDK 5.1.0. While connecting to meeting on Jitsi server (not our custom server), it throws following exception. Please check and let me know what might be wrong. Appreciate your help.

### Exception stacktrace

```
Failed to load config from https://meet.jit.si/config.js?room=<RoomName> Error(TypeError){"message":"Network request failed","stack":"index.android.bundle:116:8201\nindex.android.bundle:603:498\nvalue@index.android.bundle:29:1293\nvalue@index.android.bundle:45:3557\nindex.android.bundle:45:674\nvalue@index.android.bundle:45:2504\nvalue@index.android.bundle:45:646\nvalue@[native code]"}
```

### Conference Options snippet

```
JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder optionsBuilder =
                new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
                        .setRoom(confCode)
                        .setVideoMuted(true)
                        .setAudioMuted(true)
                        .setAudioOnly(false)
                        .setFeatureFlag("welcomepage.enabled", false)
                        .setUserInfo(userInfo);
JitsiMeetActivity.launch(this, optionsBuilder);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be occurring only on a virtual device. When I tested on a real device with Android 12 version, the meeting worked fine.